# Windows Authentication Enabled ASP.NET Web Form page Prompting Password Everytime While Accessing the Page

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-authentication

I have one 2016 server in that I have hosted the ASP.NET web form application in the IIS. While accessing that Web Site it prompts the user to enter the domain name and password after entering the credentials the form is loading. But ideally it should allow without prompting the user name and password if the Windows Authentication in Enabled. But I have another server there this issue is not happening I have compared the hosted site settings is same. I have verified the setting in the IIS for that particular site Windows Authentication is enabled and all the setting are similar like other environment.

First I have thought the Internet Options in that server causing the issue since the IIS settings are correct.

I just need to know any IIS feature or any other windows settings can cause this issue?

Already verified the Internet Options settings regarding the intranet hosted application.

I couldn't found the Difference the hosted Websites and I have other environment there the Web Site opens without prompting credentials so I need to know any other settings can cause this issue in that server.

I have verified this settings also based on the blog post [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/430348/user-login-in-asp-net-mvc-using-windows-authentica](https://stackoverflow.com)

```
* In Control Panel-> Internet Options --> Security tab of the popup window
* “Local intranet” and then on “Custom Level” settings.
* Verified the "Automatic Logon only in Intranet Zone" if other setting is enabled.
```

I coulnd't found the Difference the hosted Websites and I have other environment there the Web Site opens without prompting credentials so I need to know any other settings can cause this issue in that server.

Comment: *"Internet Options in that server"* - The Internet Options settings should be checked on the client computer, not the server. Have you done that?

Comment: Show us your `web.config` - including `<webServer>` config - you may also need to look for your `applicationHost.config` file too.

Comment: If your computer and server are joined to the same AD domain, you will not be prompted to authenticate when accessing the site. If your machine and server are not joined to the same AD domain, you will be prompted for credentials, but only if your browser first tries to authenticate with your credentials.